# "Dynamic" jQuery JSON request

Tags: jquery, json

Hello everybody and merry Christmas!

```
$.getJSON("MyURL",null ,function(result){
    $("winp").each(function () {
        var typ = $(this).attr( "type" );
        var val = result.typ;
        alert(val);
    });
});
```

I have multiple custom HTML tags like `<winp type="something"></winp>`

I get the value of "type", but when I try to show the result from the JSON request, i get 'undefined'.

Any ideas why the JSON request doesn't return anything?

Comment: please share your json response data that would be helpful to solve your problem

Comment: try console.log to see the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to get `result.something`, You should use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation)

```
var val = result[typ];
```

Comment: Sorry for not making my self clear, but you're right, that's excatly what i want.